# Doxygen for Python produces bad formatting since an update

Tags: python, doxygen, docstring

I'm using doxygen for a while to document my project. However in a new computer with a newer version of doxygen (1.9.1) it produces bad formatting for function docstrings.

I attach an image that summarises very well the issue.

[image]

The documentation right after the first line is included within a code block, not just regular text. This breaks also the special doxygen keywords. This did not happen in previous versions of doxygen, it only happens when I run doxygen in the new computer. I have not find any change in the doxygen documentation that explains that this is the (new) expected behaviour and how to avoid it.

Am I the only one having this issue?

PS: The documentation is like this:

```py
      """!Figure with the delays between source images and the composites.
  
      @param output_img name of the output file
      @param df_composites DataFrame with the composites database
      """
```

Comment: *"Am I the only one having this issue?"* That question is better placed in the projects bugtracker / support channels than on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you see in your code is caused by the, incorrect handling of the newline between the brief and param descriptions.
Removing the empty line results in the required output. like:

[image]

The handling of the extra has been fixed in the current master version of doxygen (1.9.7 (b13ed7f01ac56f89b77925037d5a00929776f4f4)).

PS. You wrote:

> However in a new computer with a newer version of doxygen (1.9.1) it produces bad formatting for function docstrings.

the doxygen 1.9.1 version is from January 8, 2021 and the current doxygen version is 1.9.6